# How to detect route direction (back or forward) while changing routes in NuxtJS?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, navigator, nuxt3

I am trying to make users close the menu instead of going to the previous route when they press the back button on their phone in my Nuxt app.

```
<script setup>
  function closeMenuOnRouteBack() {
     if (isMenuVisible) {
       isMenuVisible = false;
       navigator.preventDefault();
     }
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', closeMenuOnRouteBack());
  });

  onBeforeRouteLeave(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('popstate', closeMenuOnRouteBack());
  });
</script>
```

As you can see above, I did it but it works on both routing forwards and backwards. I want it to work only if users want to go back to the previous route. But I couldn't see any kind of keys inside the navigator object that shows the direction the user wants to go.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be an easy way to do this. But we can staging routing records somewhere to accomplish what you need:

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  // Perform actions for back or forward navigation here

  // Get the current history state object
  var currentState = event.state;

  // Get the previous history state object
  var previousState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('previousState'));

  // Store the current history state object as the previous state
  localStorage.setItem('previousState', JSON.stringify(currentState));

  // Compare the current and previous state information to determine if it's a back or forward navigation
  if (currentState && previousState && currentState.pageIndex < previousState.pageIndex) {
    // Back navigation
    alert('Back navigation triggered!');
  } else if (currentState && previousState && currentState.pageIndex > previousState.pageIndex) {
    // Forward navigation
    alert('Forward navigation triggered!');
  } else {
    // Other cases, like the initial page load or other actions
    alert('Other action triggered!');
  }
});
```